# Symfony Doctrine relationships - delete entity on the inverse side

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

my question is how to delete entity on the inverse side without going through every association and delete it manually.

```
<?php

/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $addresses;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity */
class Address
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="features")
     * @JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;
    // ...
}
```

In this example, `Address` is the owning side, so I can't delete `User` because foreign key validation will fail. I have to delete `Address` and then delete `User`. If I have 10 relationships like these the delete process is painful.

I can create `ManyToMany` relationship, but this way the `Address` entity will have `users` not `user` and I want addresses to have only one user.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You can make DB foreign key with option `ondelete=cascade`, so DB will delete all childs automatically.

Comment: Wo where should I put the onDelete? on the ManyToOne relationship?

Comment: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's helpful.
Just add cascade to inverse side entity.

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Address", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $addresses;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->addresses = new ArrayCollection();
    }
    /*
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getAddresses (){
       return $this->addresses:
    }

    /*
     * @pram Address $address
     */
    public function setAddresses (Address $address){
       $this->addresses->add ($address);
    }
}
```